# Hungarian card says MINIMUM in the description, but MAXIMUM on the top

Tags: terraforming-mars

I have a translation problem, I'm playing *Terraforming Mars* in Hungarian and the following card (original name is probably 'colonizer training station') description at the bottom says you need a MINIMUM of 5% oxygen level, but the symbol on the top says you need a MAXIMUM of 5% oxygen level.

[image]

Which one is the correct in the original version?

Comment: All Terraforming Mars project cards have a number, it's written in the tiny gray box on bottom right above the cost (2), this card is "001". The [reference](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/27696492#27696492) tells you that's project card 001: Colonizer Training Camp and tells you its prerequisites.

Comment: As a general rule, I'd expect that the icons (which don't change during localization) to be more accurate than text (which does change).  But it's always good to double check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The English text on *Colonizer Training Camp* is

> (Oxygen must be 5% or less.)

This goes with the "max 5%" icon, as you suspected.

---

[image]

*edit:* [Link to an image on BGG](https://cf.geekdo-images.com/original/img/zPMcPWpedmYLKJnd27OCACC7IN4=/0x0/pic2896671.jpg), where the English card can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum 5%**

1. The fact that the '5%' prerequisite box is red confirms it's maximum (not minimum).
2. All Terraforming Mars project cards have a number, it's written in the tiny gray box on bottom right above the cost (2), this card is "001". The [reference](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/27696492#27696492) tells you that's project card `001: Colonizer Training Camp` and tells you its prerequisites etc.:

   > Jovian tag, Building tag
   >   Cost: 8 
   >   Requires: max 5% O2 
   >   (Oxygen must be 5% or less.) 
   >   VP: 2